# Linux compatible touchscreen monitor

Tags: linux, touchscreen

Can anybody recommend a linux compatible touchscreen monitor, the criteria are:

- 19inch or greater
- 1920x1080 or better
- only single touch required
- be able to operate in portait mode

We currently have some IIyama Prolite T2250MTS monitors but these do not natively support portait mode and we have had little success getting the touch functionality working in Linux (although they do report themselves as HID devices when plugged in).

So an alternative to suggesting a monitor would be pointers to information on how we could get the IIyama monitor working in Linux.

Comment: Note: You can 'emulate' native portrait support by mirroring and swapping the axis of the input device using a small script.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with different distros? Try Fedora 13 which comes with the latest xorgs, the latest drivers for touch screens also (it says its optimized for touch screens in the release notes). Another try is openSUSE 11.3 but that will come in 60 days.

[Here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_13_announcement) is the announcement of fedora 13. (Hmm can't find it here but I read it for sure somewhere.)